# how do i convert an uncompressed key to an extended bip 32?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets

I am completely new to bitcoin. My question is how do you convert an uncompressed key to an extended bip32 key? Are there any tools that do that? Thank you

Comment: They have different use cases. A public key is for receiving sending on, an extended key is for deriving more keys from. Why do you need to convert one into the other, as opposed to creating a new one, for example?

Answer (score 1):

With "uncompressed key" you probably refers to an uncompressed **public**-key.

An extended public-key has additional informations (next to the compressed public-key itself).
You can get the pure compressed public key from an extended public key, **but not vice-versa**.

- `depth` (in the hierarchy)
- `child-index`
- `chaincode` (the hierarchal link)
- `fingerprint` (first 4 bytes of the keyId [ripemd(sha256())])